# Why is my printer assigned an incorrect/inconsistent IP address

Tags: networking, server, printing, dhcp

I recently moved and changed internet carriers (xfinity->fios). When I set up my computers and printer in my new apartment, I was no longer able to print over my WLAN, nor ping my printer.

I'm given to understand the reason for this is that my printer has been assigned an IP address that my router doesn't recognize. I have no idea why this should be so.

My printer correctly recognizes the new router, by reporting the SSID of the new router. It also recognizes its own IP address as `10.0.0.150`. Furthermore, other computers on my WLAN recognize the printer's IP as `10.0.0.150`.

However, the two computers on my WLAN have IP addresses of `192.168.1.152` and `192.168.1.157`.

I'm told that this looks as though I'm running 2 networks. One, which uses the range of addresses `192.168.1.XXX`, and another, which uses the range if addresses 10.0.0.XXX. My router's address is `192.168.1.1`. So, I believe what I need to do is ensure that all devices on my WLAN are assigned addresses from the same range of addresses.

Why was my printer assigned a `10.0.0.XXX` address, but my computers assigned addresses from the `192.168.1.XXX` range?

How do I safely ensure all my networked devices have addresses from the same range  (i.e. without needing to worry about devices conflicting over IP addresses) ? (Note:  I am currently running both Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 18.04.)

Comment: Set dedicated ip addresses for all devices in your router's configuration settings. Unless your router is an Ubuntu computer, this question is probably off-topic here.

Comment: Speaking from experience, many of the routers that ISPs provide have *very* rudimentary DHCP software. If you can assign IP addresses by MAC, that may help. Otherwise, static IPs are the way to go.